# Popular conventions that Japanese people use the Japanese characters to draw or type Emoji

Tags: usage, katakana, hiragana, kana

This question is about the popular conventions that Japanese people use the Japanese characters to draw or type Emoji.

What are some principles and conventions that Japanese people follow?

Here is one example -

Use の, へ, も, し, Diacritics (gojūon with (han)dakuten) to draw this Emoji:

[image]

My question is about the modern usages of Japanese characters. (Did these drawing/Emoji happen in the past history long ago?)

Comment: I first saw this sort of sketch using hiragana in the late 80's.  I loved it because it reminded me of a similar construction my mom used to sing to me in German [Punkt Punkt  Komma Strich](https://youtu.be/rUvcIiT46cw) which she learned from her mom.  I'd be interested to hear more about the history of this sort of sketch in Japan.

Comment: thanks A.Ellett - +1 - Do German people use German characters for drawing?

Comment: They're not saying the letters of the alphabet.  But at least in the version my mom used, which I can't quite find, everything was related to punctuation marks.  "Period, Period, Comma, Dash".  So not an exactly analogy but similar enough, or so I think.  And as I recall, with the gradual additions, as the picture developed it went from that of the face of a moon to that of a cat sitting on a shelf.

Answer (score 1):

The drawing is called [へのへのもへじ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%81%B8%E3%81%98) (so じ not し, mind the dots).

I guess this much is all most Japanese know (including me). The rest is what Google taught me.

### (Modern) variations

As such, there is no conventions or principles on how letters are used for drawing. Using them liberally, apparently [almost anything can be drawn.](https://www.pixiv.net/tags/%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%81%B8%E3%81%98/illustrations)

There are variations to へのへのもへじ(see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011165203/http://www.geocities.jp/n80da/moheji/moheji.html) for example). According to the wikipedia article above, there are region dependence and some other variations to へのへのもへじ are more common in Western Japan.

There is even a cat version.  [See this for a detailed instruction.](https://youpouch.com/2012/07/06/71911/) (The picture is taken from the link in this page.)

[image: cat ver.].

So people are still drawing by letters, but not that anything is comparable to the original へのへのもへじ.

### History

(source: [1](https://www.ndl.go.jp/kaleido/entry/6/1.html), [2](https://chebi-co.com/henoheno-mohezi/))

First, all above are called 文字絵 rather than 絵文字 (which reminds of something like  or  (^_^) which [dates back to 1986-06-02.](https://www.kk-bestsellers.com/articles/-/9716/1/)).

In Heian-period (794 - 1185), there was a type of drawing called 葦手絵, where letters were used for drawing reeds. There is no drawing left from the period, but modern reproductions look like [this](https://www.facebook.com/NDLexhibition/posts/1658560337696612/).

Later Buddhist sutras were used for drawing - but the source seems missing most images.

The origin of へのへのもへじ dates to around 17th century or later, mid Edo-period. [Hiroshige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiroshige) drew へへののもへいじ like below （read top-to-bottom, right-to-left):

[image: hiroshige]

[Hokusai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokusai) used hiragana in his [how-to book](https://pulverer.si.edu/node/314/title/2/26). This isn't exactly drawing by letters (more of making a sketch).

### Other

There is a type of songs called [絵描き歌](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%B5%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8D%E6%AD%8C) (drawing songs). This is not drawing by letters, but closer to what A.Ellett mentions in the comment. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFT3YMvgI4A) is one of the most popular, and also many people should have seen [how to draw Doraemon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxV70NIGD1o).